# Custom wildcard configuration in postfix

Tags: regex, virtual, postfix-mta

Is it possible to use wildcards in the postfix virtual file?
Instead of allowing @mydomain.com I would like to know whether I can permit a specific configuration of an email address, for example I would like all these to be accepted:

`xyzabcTRE456@mydomain.com`
`xyzabcFRS869@mydomain.com`
`xyzdefGLY643@mydomain.com`

Could I have a single line regex-type entry in the postfix virtual table to cope with these permutations?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use configuration parameter [check_recipient_access](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) in your smtpd_*_restrictions.

e.g, your `main.cf` should contains

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = other rule, other rule,..., check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/access.me,...
```

Then `/etc/postfix/access.me` should contains your regex. [This page](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) and [this page](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) should help you.

```
/^xyzabc/ OK
```